# OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file)

Tags: python-3.x, hdf5

I am trying to load a pre_trained model named "tr_model.h5" for my assignment but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "Trigger_Project.py", line 84, in <module>
model = load_model(filename)
 File "Trigger_Project.py", line 84, in <module>
model = load_model(filename)
 File "/home/neeraj/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 99, in make_fid
fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
```

File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

```
File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 78, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'tr_model.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

I have made sure that the file is present. I don't why it is showing os error. I am using linux 18.04 and all the required libraries are upgraded. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that it is a relative path issue?

Comment: No, it is in the same directory

Comment: Is there any issue where it can not be opened through terminal ?

Comment: Can you add a `print(os.getcwd())` and check that it is the correct directory you're assuming?

Comment: Yes, I did check that and it is reporting the same directory I am assuming.

Comment: All these solutions does not work for me. Interestingly, I managed to solve by uninstall the h5py package (3.15) with an older version, say, 2.15 by `pip3 install h5py==2.15`

Answer (score 5):

I encounter the same issue as I posted in my question:

[h5py.File(path) doesn't recognize folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57469102/h5py-filepath-doesnt-recognize-folder-path)

My initial reasoning is that h5py.File(path) doesn't handle the standard subfolder path as its argument, e.g. `load_model("neunet.h5")` has no issue, but `load_model("subfolder/neunet.h5")` will give the same error.

In a nutshell, my solution is to simply put whatever .h5 files into the working home folder for in my jupyter notebook, which is the place you create the .ipynb file. You could use `print(os.getcwd())` in jupyter notebook to see where is your current working directory.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when setting the path for training checkpoints using
`tensorflow.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint`
I had set my path to:

```
path = os.path.join(subdir,filename)
```

using an *f string* solved the problem:

```
path = f'{subdir}/{filename}'
```

So I would also check how you are importing the `load_model`,
try `tensorflow.keras.models` instead of only `keras.models`

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on colab and google drive, mount the drive to the colab using,

```
# Load the Drive helper and mount
from google.colab import drive

# This will prompt for authorization.
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by specifying an absolute path instead. Getting the absolute path of the working folder and then appending the path to the file from the working directory. in my case, the file is in a directory named datasets, so I tried the following code

```
file_name = os.path.dirname(__file__) +'\\datasets\\test_catvnoncat.h5'
test_dataset = h5py.File(file_name, "r")
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered with this error when I was working with docker image. Since customized docker has different path than root path, I got the same error.

> OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = '', errno = 2, error message = '**`No such file or directory`**', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)

Basically mismatch of the paths raise this error

1. Check relative, absolute path
2. Check which path your program expects

Answer (score 0):

1. If you run **a.py** got the error, but you load the **model.h5** in **b.py**
2. Please cp **model.h5** to the same level directory with **a.py**
3. Edit **b.py's load('xx/model.h5')** to **load('model.h5')**

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue in colab after mounting the drive by setting "%cd /gdrive" and when I wrote "model.save('/gdrive/mnist.h5')". Then I realised files can be created and saved in '/gdrive/My Drive/' and not just '/gdrive'. So, it is important to check if you can create files in the path specified.

So, model.save('/gdrive/My Drive/mnist.h5') worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had `loss` always equal to `inf`, therefore the model file had never been written to disk on callbacks as it had only been written for best cases for `loss`.

When I eliminated all NaN values from the dataset, all went smoothly and the model appeared on the file system.

Enabling verbosity in the callback helped to diagnose this.

For details, see the official Keras docs on callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue and get it solved by removing the project in pycharm and recreate a project in the same folder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).