# OsError : Unable to open file in pixellib

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to change background of image using pixellib library but am encountering problem. I'm getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/FEd/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/PIXEL.py", line 16, in
>
> change_bg.load_pascalvoc_model("deeplabv3_xception_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5")
> File
> "C:\Users\FEd\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pixellib\tune_bg.py",
> line 43, in load_pascalvoc_model
> self.model.load_weights(model_path)   File "C:\Users\FEd\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py",
> line 2319, in load_weights
> with h5py.File(filepath, 'r') as f:   File "C:\Users\FEd\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\h5py_hl\files.py",
> line 427, in **init**
> swmr=swmr)   File "C:\Users\FEd\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\h5py_hl\files.py",
> line 190, in make_fid
> fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)   File "h5py_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper   File
> "h5py_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
> File "h5py\h5f.pyx", line 96, in h5py.h5f.open OSError: Unable to open
> file (unable to open file: name =
> 'deeplabv3_xception_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5', errno = 2, error
> message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)

Have used `os.getcwd` to get the current working directory but still am getting same error. Have found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51593527/oserror-unable-to-open-file-unable-to-open-file) states i should use `os.getcwd` to get current working directory

**Code**

```
import pixellib
from pixellib.tune_bg import alter_bg
import os


my_dir = os.getcwd()

print(my_dir)

m1 = my_dir+"\sample.jpg"
m2 = my_dir+"\change_background.jpg"
print(m1)
print(m2)


change_bg = alter_bg()
change_bg.load_pascalvoc_model("deeplabv3_xception_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5")
change_bg.change_bg_img(f_image_path =m1, b_image_path = m2, output_image_name="new_img.jpg")

print("done")
```

Comment: @mechanical_meat am not trying to change directory i want to change the background of the picture

Comment: The error indicates that there is no file by that name in the current working directory. You should verify the location of the `deeplabv3...` file.

Comment: Ensure that "deeplabv3_xception_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5" file is downloaded and present in the current working directory or add the path to that file in the change_bg.load_pascalvoc_model( path/to/the/h5file)